# DATEDIFF with query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I want to know if i'm able to do something like this, or what can be the proper query for this?

```
DATEDIFF ( year , 
     , SELECT AVG (year(fechaBaja))FROM [erpVALLAS].[dbo].[sysCPEmpleados]
     , SELECT year(GETDATE() )
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `fechaBaja`? And what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: [PLEASE READ](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it like this

```
select   year(GETDATE())   - (select AVG (year(fechaBaja))   FROM [erpVALLAS].[dbo].[sysCPEmpleados])
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, Like this:

```
SELECT  DATEDIFF ( 
            YEAR,
            (SELECT CAST(AVG(CAST(fechaBaja AS INT)) AS DATETIME) FROM [erpVALLAS].[dbo].[sysCPEmpleados]),
            GETDATE()
        ) AS [YearDiff]
```

But I am not sure what you would want to accomplish, more details about why and what your trying to achieve would be good.

Edit: Fixed the query

Answer (score -1):

You can also set your dates in variables above to clean it up a bit. This can make it easier to understand.

```
DECLARE @startDate AS INT = (SELECT AVG(year(fechaBaja)) FROM [erpVALLAS].[dbo].[sysCPEmpleados])
DECLARE @endDate AS INT = (SELECT YEAR(GETDATE()))

SELECT  DATEDIFF ( 
        Y, 
        @startDate,
        @endDate
    ) AS yearDiff
```

Comment: Best to avoid abbreviating date parts. Should use YEAR, DAY, etc.